# Find a vector of magnitude $10$ which is perpendicular to $(4,5,-2)$

Tags: vectors

Let $(4,5,-2) = a$.
The vector that is perpendicular to $a$ be $b$.
I understand that by using dot product i will get $a\cdot b=0$ but how do i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The dot product is a good idea. Any vector $(x,y,z)$ that satisfies
$$(x,y,z) \cdot (4,5,-2) = 0 \iff 4x+5y-2z = 0$$
is perpendicular to $(4,5,-2)$.

Can you pick one with length $10$?

If not, pick any and normalize it; then multiply by $10$.

**Hint:**

> From $4x+5y-2z = 0$, an easy start would be taking $y=0$ and then $x=1$ and $z=2$ clearly fits. Now scale it appropriately so its magnitude is $10$.

Comment: it might be a little confusing that you name the coordinates $a$, $b$ and $c$ because originally $a$ and $b$ are vectors.

Comment: Agreed; although the vectors (in the question) were bold before your edit ;-). I'll edit to avoid confusion.

Comment: well, some were bold and some were not... thumbs up for the edit ;)